# yum whatprovides does not return anything

Tags: yum, rpm

I am trying to figure out what RPM provided /usr/bin/java. However, I think this may have been installed outside of yum. Is it possible for yum to tell me what provided /usr/bin/java if it wasn't installed via yum? It could have been installed using `rpm ivh`. The reason I am asking is because I am administering a test system and I need to ensure that I repeat the same steps of a previous administrator to provide instructions to the production staff. I cannot find the original RPM nor any record of how /usr/bin/java was installed. Currently, I have 7u45.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On RHEL `/usr/bin/java` is a symlink to `/etc/alternatives/java` which is managed by `alternatives`. There is not a single package that provides `/usr/bin/java`. If you want to look for packages that contain Java, use `yum whatprovides '*/java'`

Comment: Thanks for the info. Oracle provides a JRE RPM. So using `yum whatprovides '*/java'` would tell me that ?

Comment: No, `yum whatprovides` only searches in the yum repositories (as listed in `/etc/yum.repos.d/`. If you want to find which package installed `/usr/bin/java`, use `rpm -qf /usr/bin/java`